# Node.js GET error with discord.js when fetching data from atomicassets (wax.atomichub.io)

Tags: node.js, json, get, discord.js, atomicassets

I'm trying to get a discord bot to post a message in discord listing some JSON requested from [AtomicAssets](https://wax.atomichub.io). With `curl` it works fine and I get JSON back (`curl "http://test.wax.api.atomicassets.io/atomicassets/v1/assets"`)

The problem is that when I run my bot and tell it to fetch the JSON, I get this error message:

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND https://test.wax.api.atomicassets.io/atomicassets
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:67:26) {
  errno: -3008,
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'https://test.wax.api.atomicassets.io/atomicassets'
}
```

Why can't it just do the same as `curl`?

Here's a minimal working example of my `bot.js` file:

```
// stores API keys in separate JSON file
const { token } = require('./token.json');

// require the discord.js module
const Discord = require('discord.js');

// create a new Discord client
const bot = new Discord.Client();

// auth
bot.login(token);

bot.on('message', message => {

    // fetch AtomicAssets items
    else if (message.content === 'assets') {
        const http = require('http')
        const options = {
            hostname: 'http://test.wax.api.atomicassets.io/atomicassets',
            path: '/v1/assets',
            method: 'GET'
        }

        const req = http.request(options, res => {
            console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`)

            req.on('data', d => {
                process.stdout.write(d)
                return message.reply(d)
            })
        })

        req.on('error', error => {
            console.error(error)
        })

        req.end()
    }
});
```

Using Postman I get JSON in return too, so I'm sure the error is somewhere in my code.

I've also tried to use AtomicAssets' [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/atomicassets), but to no avail.

Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) module. The usage is simple:

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

fetch('http://test.wax.api.atomicassets.io/atomicassets/v1/assets')
.then(res => res.json())
.then(json => console.log(json));
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
        const req = https.request(options, res => {
            console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`)
/*           v  HERE */
            res.on('data', d => {
/*           ^   HERE*/
                process.stdout.write(d)
                return message.reply(d)
            })
        })

        req.on('error', error => {
            console.error(error)
        })
```

Shouldn't be "req" and not "res" ?
(If it's not sovling the problem please tell me so i delete this ^^')

Comment: ok thanks I'll try that and let you know if it works

Comment: No I'm afraid that didn't do the trick @87message.author.username7